# ms access , the expression you entered has a function name that microsoft access can't find

Tags: vba, ms-access

i have a 2007 ms access application , and it is working fine between multiple computers, but now we have a new pc that joined the network and it is running with windows 10 , and has ms access 2013 installed, and when i try to use the application in that new pc, i am geting the above error (2950), and i have tried the following solutions :

1. setting a trusted path for my db.
2. using compact and repair the database. but it did not work

so, if any idea i will be very thankful..

Comment: On the new machine, open VBA editor and see if there are any missing References.

Comment: you were absolutely right, there was a missing references , I unchecked then re checked closed the application and reopen it and everything was fine , thanks a lot  .

Comment: Just one? You compiled (not compact) your vba code? Some classes changed their version in Win10, e.g. XmlHttp40 to XmlHttp60?

Answer (score 0):

I recently did some testing with macros on a Windows 10 machine and had to change the following in the code:

OLD   Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;

NEW   Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;

to get our macros to work............